# Copy a CVS project into another CVS project

Tags: maven, copy, migration, repository, cvs

In our CVS repository our projects look like this:

```
- app-parent
- app-backend
- app-gui
- app-common
```

Now I want to represent the Maven structure of our projects also in our CVS repository. So the repository should then look like this:

```
- app-parent
    - app-backend
    - app-gui
    - app-common
```

How can I *copy* a CVS project into another CVS project? I also want to copy the CVS history of the files and folders in this step.

---

If it isn't possible with keeping the history then it'd also be OK with losing it. :-)

Comment: If you really need to have the history as well you need to modifiy the repository on the repository itself which does not make sense. Furthermore i would suggest to migrate to SVN/Git etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise As far as I know the Git migration is only possible once there's a hierarchy in the project. How can I do it *with* losing the history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply copied the directories on the file system with `cp -rp`.